# Determining amount of padding added to ethernet frame

Tags: c, linux-kernel, padding, linux-device-driver

I am working on a driver for the Linux kernel. For the success of my project, I need to determine the amount of padding added to Ethernet frames smaller than the minimum size of 60 bytes (not counting the FCS). I am not generating these frames; I am receiving them on a NIC for processing.

Having a `struct sk_buff`, is it possible to determine the amount of trailing zeros added to the packet directly?

I can of course determine that value by going through the entire packet, figuring out where the content of the highest layer ends and then simply subtracting that position from the frame size (in this case, 60 bytes). But is there a more efficient way to do it directly from the information stored on a `struct sk_buff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As far as I know, there is no way to check for zero padding directly using the sk_buff structure without actually looking at the ethernet header, which is simple enough.

That said, with some simple pointer arithmetic and byte subtraction, you can use the length field in IP data to figure out the padding.

This is a good reference for sk_buff:
http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html

And here is a good reference for the packet structure, showing the 'length' field in the bottom picture within 'data'.

http://nerdcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Ethernet-Frame-Explained.png

I think this is the way it must be done, but it doesn't require parsing as you had previously maintained.  The header/data structure fields are set up such that they can be referenced/stripped directly via pointer/array without parsing, and then by subtracting header+data length from raw packet length you can get the padding, all without inspecting the data.

Hope that helps.

Also, for best practice, you should probably have your driver account for both versions of 802.3 in use.  You can do so by inspecting the Ethertype/length field.  If the value is greater than 1536 (0x0600) than you know it's an Ethernet II type packet and the field contains an ethertype, which tells you what the ethernet packet encapsulates.  There are some popular ones if you Wikipedia for "Ethertype."

For example, IP = 0x0800.  If the field designates an Ethertype, you must resort to finding the data length field inside in order to find the padding.  If it does not, which alot of Ethernet based LAN's still don't, then you can directly use the field specified as length to do your job.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not quite sure I get it. I am pretty familiar with the `sk_buff` structure and could follow your line of thought, but an Ethernet header does not contain the frame length (it contains only the sender/receiver MAC addresses and the EtherType field). Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misspoke.  There is sometimes a 'length' field in the header, but that is not something you should count on-- nor is it what I had intended to refer to.  The 'length' field I refer to is not part of the header.  Check this out:

http://nerdcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Ethernet-Frame-Explained.png

You want the length field listed at the bottom.  Using that and the size of the other things in the field, you can figure out the amount of padding.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ethernet II frames do indeed have a type field, but 802.3 Ethernet frames use that field for the length. (Ethernet II types all have high numerical values that cannot be confused with length, so you can tell which you are dealing with.) But if you are dealing with Ethernet II and you have padded frames then you must rely on the encapsulated protocol for the actual length; you cannot obtain it from the Ethernet header. Here's a reference: http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~lewis/networkpages/m04s03EthernetFrame.htm

Comment: Note the reference given by @Nick is specifically for the Internet Protocol (IP). If the questioner is worried about padding added to Ethernet frames then the frames of interest are probably not IP.

Comment: Well, basically the reply to my answer is then 'no'. That's what I thought; you really need to decapsulate a raw packet to get the lenght field from the IP header and from there determine the amount of padding introduced. @NickLindberg: perhaps you could update your answer to make it more clear so I can mark it as 'the answer'? ;)

Comment: Heh-- ok, edited.  Quick question though, why do you need to do this?  Unless it's a homework assignment of some kind, there's no reason you should have to strip zero padding in a driver, unless you are DMA'ing data directly into a QP in the stack or something.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 does almost the same, there is probably no better ways. Check ip_rcv():

```
len = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
if (skb->len < len) {
        IP_INC_STATS_BH(dev_net(dev), IPSTATS_MIB_INTRUNCATEDPKTS);
        goto drop;
} else if (len < (iph->ihl*4))
        goto inhdr_error;

/* Our transport medium may have padded the buffer out. Now we know it
 * is IP we can trim to the true length of the frame.
 * Note this now means skb->len holds ntohs(iph->tot_len).
 */
if (pskb_trim_rcsum(skb, len)) {
        IP_INC_STATS_BH(dev_net(dev), IPSTATS_MIB_INDISCARDS);
        goto drop;
}
```